# Altering XMP metadata of a PDF with R

Tags: r, pdf

I am trying to alter metadata of a PDF like Author or Keyword. I noticed that this is stored in XMP-Format which can be read in an XML-style. For example:

```
<rdf:Description xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/" xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/" xmlns:photoshop="http://ns.adobe.com/photoshop/1.0/" xmlns:xmpRights="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/rights/"><pdf:Producer>MicrosoftÂ® ExcelÂ® for Microsoft 365</pdf:Producer>
<pdf:Keywords>DocumentType=MR;PublicationCountry=SSSG,LI,CH,AT,DE;Language=en;ShareClass=Class;DisseminationRecipient=LGTB;RecordDate=2022-12-31</pdf:Keywords>
<dc:creator>
<rdf:Seq><rdf:li>Max</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator><dc:subject>
<rdf:Bag><rdf:li>DocumentType=MR</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>PublicationCountry=SG,LI,CH,AT,DE</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>Language=en</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>ShareClass=Class</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>DisseminationRecipient=LGTB</rdf:li>
<rdf:li>RecordDate=2022-12-31</rdf:li>
</rdf:Bag></dc:subject><xmp:CreatorTool>MicrosoftÂ® ExcelÂ® for Microsoft 365</xmp:CreatorTool>
<xmp:CreateDate>2023-01-05T11:32:59+08:00</xmp:CreateDate>
<xmp:ModifyDate>2023-01-05T11:48:27+08:00</xmp:ModifyDate>
<xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:B60CAE44-677E-45B6-9436-60F74892C0FC</xmpMM:DocumentID>
<xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:B60CAE44-677E-45B6-9436-60F74892C0FC</xmpMM:InstanceID>
<xmp:MetadataDate>2023-01-05T11:48:27+08:00</xmp:MetadataDate></rdf:Description></rdf:RDF></x:xmpmeta>
```

Is there a way to edit this data in R?

Since I am not aware of a package I intended to do it via simply editing the text:

```
data <- readLines("PDFFILE.pdf")
Warning:
In readLines("H:/Daten/Projekte/PDFFILE.pdf") :
  incomplete final line found in 'H:/Daten/projekte...
```

Will this be possible without destroying the PDF?

**Edit:**
I am aware of Exiftool, pdftk and other tools. However, I cannot download them on my system. This is why I would like to edit the XML representation directly.

Comment: Look at the exiftoolr package.  The exiftool utility that it interfaces to supports PDF.

Comment: This package will only work when a command line tool such as exiftool is installed. this unfortunately is not an optoin for me since i cannot use these kind of tools.